# What is the connotation of calling someone "Kozaru Shichinosuke"?

Tags: meaning, culture, names

What is the meaning of calling someone "Kozaru Shichinosuke". I know it's the title of a [kabuki play](http://www.kabuki21.com/kozaru_shichinosuke.php) and the name of the hero, however what's the linguistic connotation here?

Is it a phrase used in common language now? Or is it limited to people knowing the play?

---

The situation is: person A helped person B (brought forgotten thing) and person B responds with 小猿七之助だ.

Person B is very old fashioned, person A is not particularly happy with the response.

Comment: 少なくとも私はまったく知らない人物です。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think 小猿七之助 is known to most Japanese people. Judging from the plot, I felt a negative word 日和見主義者 ("opportunist") would describe his character. But I don't know if it fits the context.